# Дан массив: $arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]; С помощью функции array_splice сделайте из него следующий массив: [1, 'a', 'b', 2, 3, 4, 'c', 5, 'e']

Tags: php, массивы, функции

Не понимаю как это можно сделать. Либо в условии задачи ошибка? Максимум что я могу сделать, это вставить элементы в одном месте:
**$arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
$arr_splice = array_splice($arr, 1, 0, ['a', 'b']);**
Как вставлять сразу в нескольких местах я нигде информации не нашёл. помогите разобраться.

Comment: Никакой скрытой магии в функции `array_splice` нету, да и в условии вам не сказано, что добавить все элементы нужно единожды вызвав эту функцию.

Comment: Я почему то решил что надо один раз написать функцию. Спасибо

Answer (score 2):

```php
$arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]; 
array_splice($arr, 4, 0, ['c']);
array_splice($arr, 6, 0, ['e']);
array_splice($arr, 1, 0, ['a', 'b']);
var_dump($arr)."\n";
```

Результат:

> array(9) {
> [0] => int(1)
> [1] => string(1) "a"
> [2] => string(1) "b"
> [3] => int(2)
> [4] => int(3)
> [5] => int(4)
> [6] => string(1) "c"
> [7] => int(5)
> [8] => string(1) "e"
> }